# Headless chrome is working with terminal but not working with setting arguments

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run chrome in headless mode, my chrome version is **62.0**, chrome driver version is **3.6.0** and I am using **ubuntu 16.04**, when I am trying to run headless chrome through terminal it is working in headless mode, but when I am trying to run it through code it is not working in headless mode. Can anyone suggest me the perfect way to make it work through code? and what changes I suppose to do in code snippet?.Following is the code snippet I am using.

```
        ChromeOptions option=new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("--headless");
        option.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,option);
        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: what are the error in LOGS

Comment: there are no errors and exceptions occurring in code.

Comment: Note that depending on the architecture you're running on you may need to use a different *chomedriver*. For example if you're running on a raspberry with an *ARMvX* architecture (in that case [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67628/latest-firefox-chrome-possibilities) might help).

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `my chrome version is 62.0, chrome driver version is 3.6.0 and I am using ubuntu 16.04`. Ensure that you are using the latest `Selenium distro v3.6.0` and `chromedriver.exe v2.33` along with `Chrome v62.0`

While we work with **`Selenium v3.6.0`** you can simply use **`ChromeOptions`** Class to work with **`Chrome in Headless Mode`** as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
System.out.println("Chrome in Headless Mode");
```